# c++ setter coding convention. what should be the input variable name?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I tried to follow [google c++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) . i have a setter for private memeber - age.

My problem is what should be the name of the setAge argument?
In java i have both the same name and ditinguish between them by using the this keyword.

```
void setAge(int age){
     this.age = age;
}
```

What is the coding style to do this in c++ (google coding style is preferred).

Comment: I would suggest using `m_age` or `age_` for data members. Which convention doesn't matter, as long as it is clear from reading a block of code what variables are data members and which aren't.

Comment: I prefer to do the java way, but how can i do it in c++? so i need to have 2 different names. i dont think that the change should be in the class member name. the class member name if i understand corect google style should be without any symbol. we don’t need them in modern IDEA.

Comment: You can do the same thing in C++ as you do in Java, just change `this.age` to `this->age`

Comment: Benjamin Lindley, but is it "acceptable" ?

Comment: Not by my standards, I follow the style that juanchopanza suggested.  Private members are suffixed with an underscore.  But you're free to do it.  It's perfectly legal C++.

Comment: @user1495181 Are you up for a code review? I think you'll find that opinions vary on what is acceptable. I would try and form your own unless you're in an environment where someone else's opinion is all that counts. In that case I'd ask them.

Comment: @user1495181 Since you asked I would follow Benjamin and juanchopanza and use a prefix/suffix for your member variables.

Comment: @user - Large parts of the Google style guide is specific to maintaining Google's old pre-standard code base. It is not a very good guide to follow for new code.

Comment: Bo Persson, what do you recommand for a new code. develop with IDE? do you have any reference to new code standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google C++ coding standards suggest that you add a [trailing underscore to class data members](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Variable_Names#Variable_Names). I think it is very important to follow this, otherwise you are guaranteed to hide a class data member with a local variable name.

Concerning getters and setters, I personally find `getX` and `setX` convenciton tedious, when it is obvious what a method does.

```
int age() const; // gets age, what else could it do?

void age(int age); // sets age, following the principle of least surprise.
```

Comment: You are correct!!! my mistake . google advice  trailing underscore to class data members. so there is no problem. what do they mean Common Variable names (section above this)? and global name? thank you!!!!

Comment: @user1495181 common variables could be those defined locally in a function. Global ones could be declared in a header that is used by many different code components.

Comment: It's a bad idea to give two functions the same name when they have different semantics. Getting a value and setting a value are different semantics, so they should have different names. It's OK to drop the "get" prefix, but I'd keep the "set" prefix so you can see where the value is being changed and where state is mutated. Consider, for example, if there is more than one age: `age(6,1);` sets the seventh age, and `age(6)` gets the seventh age, but is indistinguishable from a function that sets the only age.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is really irrelevant provided you follow *some* convention. I tend to use `newAge` (or `new_age` if you *really* want to follow the Google guidelines) for the `setAge()` argument.

Comment: did i understand correct Google coding style, do class members dosnt need any appending symbol? thank you

Comment: @user1495181, the guidelines state that class member variables (which is not what you asked about) should have a trailing underscore, local variables don't. However, there's no specific rule for formal parameters to a function (which you _did_ ask about) so I'm assuming you use the standard variable naming rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

I follow the "standard library convention". Both getter and setter are called like the property:

```
void size(size_t size);
size_t size() const;
```

The private member has the same name with a trailing underscore:

```
 size_t size_;
```

Comment: A trailing underscore is hard to see in some fonts, and should be avoided.

Comment: I which programming targeted fonts (Courier New, Consolas, ...) is a trailing underscore hard to see?

Comment: In most of them.  One of the arguments for using an underscore in variable names (instead of camel case) is that it looks like a space, which is what you'd use in English.  In the middle of a symbol, there's generally no ambiguity, because there aren't many constructs in C++ where you'd place two user defined symbols separated by only a white space.  Leading and trailing underscore, however, are easily overlooked.

Comment: I honestly never had a problem with trailing underscores - hell even Google seems to recommend them - but a leading underscore is just a disaster waiting to happen... Somehow this sounds more like a theoretical argument based maybe on bad editors...

Comment: A leading underscore is certainly a lot worse than a trailing one.  But even a trailing one is not as good as the alternatives I've seen: `myName` or `m_name`.

Comment: i hate the m_ version as it leads to stupid conventions like c_ and s_ ... Neither do I see a compelling reason how myXYZ would be better... "my" adds 0 information in my book...

Comment: I wasn't a great fan of `m_name` myself to begin with---it looks too much like Hungarian.  But I've gotten used to it, and it _is_ clear and concise.  As for `my`, the `my` adds exactly the same information as the trailing underscore, but is visible regardless of the font, and is pronounceable.

Comment: Semantically "my" adds rather useless information... As I seldomly have getters/setters - good design almost forbids a buch of public properties [IMHO] I have no problem with the 1-2 members that feature a trailing underscore...

Comment: Too many getters and setters is an indication of poor design.  But the `my` adds _exactly_ the same semantic information as your trailing underscore, you can't say that one is useless, and the other isn't.  The only difference is that `my` is pronounceable, and is visible regardless of the font.

Comment: "my" is semantically redundant as it adds the information that the member is from me, which is already expressed via this->; therefor myXYZ is 100% redundant, the trailing underscore on the other hand is just necessary 'cause C++ can't differentiate members and member functions based on the identifier. And as I already said, I never had any problem seeing the trailing underscore...

Comment: The `my` or the `m_` means _exactly_ what the trailing underscore means, no more, no less.  They're just arbitrary conventions.  With the difference that 1) `my` and `m_` are clearly visible to everyone, in all fonts, and 2) `my`, and to a lesser degree `m_`, are easily pronounceable when talking about code.

Comment: The standard library uses resize(size_t), not size(size_t). It's a bad idea for two functions with the same name to have semantics as different as setting and getting.

Comment: @Brangdon wait what? You must oppose the use of operator[] for getting and setting of values than too... Not to mention that resize has implications that are for bigger than just setting the value of the internal member...

Comment: @MFH No, both overloads of operator[] return a reference, so both are doing the same thing. There's also no confusion when used; the assignment syntax is clear. Whether or not resize() does more than setting a member, I don't believe there is any size(size_t) in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Any naming convention is more or less arbitrary, but in this case, the
obvious solution would be:

```
void setAge( int newValue /* or newAge */ );
```

Depending on the local conventions, the function may be named `setAge`,
or simply `age`; in the latter case, you have need some sort of
convention to distinguish between the function and the data member.
Most places I've seen use either `m_age` or `myAge` for the data member
(with `s_age` or `ourAge` for static data members); either will do the
trick.  (I've also seen `_age` and `age_`.  Generally speaking, however,
it's best to avoid leading and trailing `_`, since they tend to be
difficult to see with some fonts.)

Answer (score 0):

Im personally following java conventions in cpp. So assuming you want to name your property "new age" the member would be named `newAge`. The getter would then be named `getNewAge()` and the setter `setNewAge(int newAge)`.

Comment: why append new. this is not java convention. i jave getter and setter input will be the same name as the memeber.

Comment: @user1495181 the answere was poorly formulated. I wanted to show the naming convention when the property contains multiple words. Therefor the property name is simply `newAge`.